# Is there any way siblings could be related more than 3/4th siblings, but less than full siblings?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, gene

I couldn’t find anything on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_relationship). 3/4th siblings are 37.5% related while full siblings are 50% related. Is there anything in between?

Comment: You may be confusing averages with the actual (genomic) relatedness of two given siblings. Two given siblings can in theory be anywhere from 0% to 100% related, but on average will be 50% related.

Answer (score 4):

The [International Society of Genetic Genealogy Wiki](https://isogg.org/wiki/Three-quarter_sibling) provides the following situations for which siblings may be considered $3/4$ siblings (a coefficient of relationship of 37.5):

> - a man has children with each of two sisters (the children are related    as half-siblings and first cousins)
> - a woman has children by each of    two brothers (the children are related as half-siblings and first    cousins)
> - a woman has children with both a man and his father (the    children are related as half-siblings and half-aunt or half-uncle and
>   half-niece or half-nephew)
> - a man has children with both a woman and    her daughter (the children are related as half-siblings and half-aunt    or half-uncle
>   and half-niece or half-nephew)

Note that the above situations assume that all *grandparents* are unrelated. If you consider a situation where either or both sets of grandparents are full siblings, then you have a coefficient of relationship in the sibling grandchildren that is intermediate between 37.5 and 50.

Comment: I edited my question, what I wrote was not what I meant.

Comment: I've extended my answer